# Possible bug with getTransitions in PHP 8.1?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I know a lot of date-related bugs have been [fixed in PHP 8.1](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-8.php#8.1.0), but it may have introduced new ones...

Take this code:

```
$time_zone_id = 'America/Vancouver';
$timeZone = new DateTimeZone($time_zone_id);
$trans = $timeZone->getTransitions(time(), strtotime('+1 year', time()));
print_r($trans);
```

In **PHP 7.3, 7.4** & **8.0**, it outputs the daylight savings time transitions for the next year (starting with the current state):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ts] => 1647637122
            [time] => 2022-03-18T20:58:42+0000
            [offset] => -25200
            [isdst] => 1
            [abbr] => PDT
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ts] => 1667725200
            [time] => 2022-11-06T09:00:00+0000
            [offset] => -28800
            [isdst] => 
            [abbr] => PST
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ts] => 1678615200
            [time] => 2023-03-12T10:00:00+0000
            [offset] => -25200
            [isdst] => 1
            [abbr] => PDT
        )

)
```

But in **PHP 8.1**, it returns only the current state:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ts] => 1647637451
            [time] => 2022-03-18T21:04:11+0000
            [offset] => -25200
            [isdst] => 1
            [abbr] => PDT
        )

)
```

Am I missing something or is it a bug?

Comment: I thought for a moment PHP might have gotten [ahead of itself](https://vancouversun.com/news/local-news/u-s-legislative-action-spells-end-of-time-changes-for-bc) but this is apparently [an open bug](https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/7752).

Comment: Dang it!  I had searched for such a bug report, but I did it at [bugs.php.net](https://bugs.php.net/).  Seems confusing to have two places for bugs...  Anyway, thanks @rickdenhaan!

Comment: Well, to be fair, I got the Github link from https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81660 ;-)

Comment: Ah...  Since it's flagged as a duplicate of the GitHub bug, it doesn't show up when doing a 'plain' search. This is why I missed it. ... Poking at it it a bit more, I now realize that doing a simple Google search for `getTransitons bug php` gives me both the issues (and, now, this question). No need to got the specific bug trackers.  Lesson learned.  :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed in **PHP 8.1.6**.  So, the bug is present in PHP 8.1.0 thru 8.1.5.